# Add windows folder in Dockerfile

Tags: windows, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I have dockerfile for nodejs and mongodb installation.I installed docker plug-in and created a job in that. Now i need to build the image from the Dockerfile. I have to apply copy command in Dockerfile, to copy the nodejs app into container.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

#OS Update
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install git git-core unzip python-pip make wget build-essential python-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libssl-dev vim nano net-tools iputils-ping supervisor curl supervisor

WORKDIR /home/wipro
#Mongo Setup
RUN curl -O http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.2.tgz && tar -xzvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.2.tgz && cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.2/bin && cp * /usr/bin/
#RUN mongod --dbpath /home/azureuser/CI_service/data/ --logpath /home/azureuser/CI_service/log.txt --logappend --noprealloc --smallfiles --port 27017 --fork

#Node Setup
#RUN curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz && tar -xzvf node-v0.12.7.tar.gz && cd node-v0.12.7
#RUN cd /opt/node-v0.12.7 && ./configure && make && make install
#RUN cp /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/ && cp /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/
RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN cd /usr/local && sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xzf /home/wipro/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN npm install forever -g

#CI SERVICE
ADD prod /home/wipro/
ADD servicestart.sh /home/wipro/
RUN chmod +x /home/wipro/servicestart.sh
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["sh", "/home/wipro/servicestart.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 27017
```

Here in dockerfile, I'm trying to Add prod and servicestart.sh into image.In linux its possible. I'm new to windows. How to add those files into image from Windows.?

While building the job, facing issue in docker plug-in

```
FATAL: uri was not specified java.lang.NullPointerException: uri was not specified
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)    
at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientConfig$DockerClientConfigBuilder.withUri(DockerClientConfig.java:406)     
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.createDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:120)    
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder$DescriptorImpl.getDockerClient(DockerBuilder.java:204)   
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.dockerbuildstep.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:68)   
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)    
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:814)    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)  
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)  
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:593)    
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1567)  
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)  
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)  
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)
```

What URI need to specify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure those files are:

- in the same folder as the Dockerfile, in order to be part of the [docker build **context**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/),
- in a folder starting with `c:\Users\<yourLogin>`, since only that folder is mounted in the VM boot2docker TiynyCore-based Linux host.

[The OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2439278/user2439278) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284683/add-windows-folder-in-dockerfile/35284739?noredirect=1#comment58324068_35284739) using the [Docker build step plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin), with the URI

```
docker daemon -D -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
```

Comment: Do we need to install docker in windows. While building, Im getting error as docker server URL not specified in Jenkins

Comment: Error message : FATAL: uri was not specified

Comment: @user2439278 if your slave execute docker commands on Windows, docker-machine needs to be installed (just one exe to copy from https://github.com/docker/machine/releases), and the command returned by `docker-machine env` need to be executed for any docker command to work.

Comment: docker toolkit and docker machine installed in my Windows.How to proceed now?

Comment: @user2439278 forget tookit, just docker-machine.exe is enough: `docker-machine create` and then execute the result of `docker-machine env`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102961/discussion-between-user2439278-and-vonc).

Comment: docker-machine.exe downloaded as mentioned in above link. Now when i tried to create docker-machine create , it asks for drive name? what i need to specify?

Comment: @user `docker-machine create -d virtualbox default` (assuming virtualbox is installed)

Comment: Error message : "This computer does'nt have VT-X/AMD-v enabled.Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory". I'm using azure windows server

Comment: @user2439278 I thought you were on a regular windows box. For Azure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-docker-machine/, using the azure driver: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/azure/

Comment: instead of Windows,if i use ubuntu server ,do we neeed virtualbox to run the docker-machine create

Comment: @user2439278 no docker-machine required there: just `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` or more recent installation process like https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

Comment: So , in ubuntu azure sever, just docker need to be installed right?

Comment: @user2439278 correct, since docker runs natively on (recent) Linux kernel. No need for VM there.

Comment: So then what URI i need to specify in Jenkins (For docker)

Comment: @user2439278 are you using the docker jenkins plugin (this one: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+build+step+plugin) ? Or this one? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

Comment: I installed both the plugins in jenkins

Comment: @user2439278 What URI did you end up using?

Comment: started docker service : docker daemon -D -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376

Comment: @user2439278 Great! Which of the two Docker Jenkins plugin did you use?

Comment: Docker build step plugin

Comment: i can able to create image from dockerfile. But unable to start the container. Created a new Question for this :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293195/unable-to-start-container-from-jenkins

kindly help to fix