# Unable to start container from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-docker

In Jenkins I installed Docker build step plugin.
In Jenkins, created job and in it, executed docker command selected build image. The image is created using the Dockerfile.The Dockerfile is :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest


#OS Update
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install git git-core unzip python-pip make wget build-essential python-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libssl-dev vim nano net-tools iputils-ping supervisor curl supervisor

WORKDIR /home/wipro
#Mongo Setup
RUN curl -O http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.2.tgz && tar -xzvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.2.tgz && cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.0.2/bin && cp * /usr/bin/
#RUN mongod --dbpath /home/azureuser/CI_service/data/ --logpath /home/azureuser/CI_service/log.txt --logappend --noprealloc --smallfiles --port 27017 --fork

#Node Setup
#RUN curl -O https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7.tar.gz && tar -xzvf node-v0.12.7.tar.gz && cd node-v0.12.7
#RUN cd /opt/node-v0.12.7 && ./configure && make && make install
#RUN cp /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/ && cp /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/bin/
RUN wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN cd /usr/local && sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xzf /home/wipro/node-v0.12.7-linux-x64.tar.gz
RUN npm install forever -g

#CI SERVICE
ADD prod /home//
ADD servicestart.sh /home/
RUN chmod +x /home/servicestart.sh
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["sh", "/home/servicestart.sh"]

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 27017
```

Then I tried to create the container and container is created.
When I tried to start the container, the container is not running.
When I checked with command:

```
docker ps -a
```

, it shows status as `created` only.
Its not in running or `Exited` state.

The output of `docker ps -a` is:

docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8ac762c4dc84        d85c2d90be53        "sh /home/servi"   15 hours ago        Created                                 hungry_liskov
7d8864940515        d85c2d90be53        "sh /home/servi"   16 hours ago        Created                                 ciservice
```

How to start the container using jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your container main command (`ENTRPOINT` + `CMD`)

A created state (for non data-volume container) means the main command failed to execute.
Try a `docker logs <container_id>` to see if there is any error message recorded.

`CMD ["sh", "/home/servicestart.sh"]` should be:

```
CMD ["/home/servicestart.sh"]
```

(The default `ENTRYPOINT` for Ubuntu should be `["sh", "-c"]`, so no need to repeat an `"sh"`)

Comment: In jenkins, i had given command to start the container as sh /home/servicestart.sh

when i checked the logs, getting error as "No such container"

Comment: @user2439278 check if you are using the right container id for your `docker logs` command: what `docker ps -a` returns?

Comment: @user2439278 OK. What `docker logs 8ac762c4dc84` return?

Comment: Error: No such container: 8ac762c4dc84

Comment: @user2439278 strange, but possible considering it is its abbreviated ID. Try `docker logs hungry_liskov`

Comment: It retruns nothing :(

Comment: @user2439278 OK then. Try the CMD I mention in my answer to see if the logs are more complete.

Comment: If i run docker run command directly in terminal,i can able to view the logs and status shows Exited. But when i start through docker plugin in jenkins, im unable to view logs and status is in Created only.

Comment: any other jenkins plugin available to start the docker container?

Comment: @user2439278 Try a regular custom Jenkins job where you would type the `docker` commands in a build step, in order to try and reproduce what you are typing successfully in command line. Make sure `CMD` (in your Dockerfile) is a I mention in the answer though.